# C++, What does this code says?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a delphi guy, pretty drunk here and trying to figure out what does this C++ code here but have no idea.. thanx

```
char sc[] = "\x31.....";


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int (*f)();
    f = (int (*)())sc;
    (int)(*f)();
}
```

"sc" is a char

Comment: by the way, look up function pointers.

Comment: char sc[] = "\x31.....

Comment: Please the whole thing. Probably some precompiled stuff hich will work only with that platform/compiler/calling convention etc.etc.

Comment: obviously he is trying to call assembly language in the code. sc is some code in machine code, and he uses a function pointer to call it.

Comment: `sc` is not "a char".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's walk through the lines one at a time:

```
int (*f)();
```

This declares a variable named `f` that's a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns an `int`.

```
f = (int (*)())sc;
```

The parenthesized part here is the type `int (*)()`, the type of a pointer to a function taking in no arguments and returning an `int`. This is a typecast that cases `sc` to a function of that type, then assigns it to `f`. Since `sc` seems to be a `char` array, this means "treat the bytes in the array `sc` as code for a function that takes no arguments and returns an `int`." This will lead to undefined behavior in the C++ spec, and depending on your system, that function might work, or it might crash due to no-execute bits set on the page containing the code.

```
(int)(*f)();
```

This is needlessly complicated. The `(int)` is a typecast of the expression `(*f)()`. Here, `(*f)` is the function pointed at by `f`, and `()` invokes it. Therefore, this means "invoke the function pointed at by `f`, then cast the result to an `int`." Of course, `f` already returns an `int`, so the cast is meaningless. As I mentioned above, this results in undefined behavior.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Addition: this type of code is usually seen in system/embedded programmming. `sc` usually is a `char`, `int_32`,`int_64`, or `void*` (depending on your platform) with something like `int sc = 0x5C`, and it is casted to a function to be called to invoke some other system functions with this address.